# How to prevent pcre(C library) to continue matching when it failed in one string?

Tags: c++, c, regex, pcre

If I have a string and a pattern:

```
char src[]="\"http://www.aaa.cn\"</tab><tab>\"www.bbb.com\""; 
char pattern[] = "\"http:\/\/.*\.com\"";
```

Then it returns `"http://www.aaa.cn\"</tab><tab>\"www.bbb.com"` to me (it failed but continue matching next characters).

I just want  some like `"http://www.aaa.com"`, `"http://www.bbb.com"`, not like that combined string.

Can someone help me out? Should I change my pattern or add some arguments to `pcre_compile()` and `pcre_exec()` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
char pattern[] = "\"http://[^\"]*\"";
```

Better yet, don't parse HTML (or fragments thereof or XML) with regexen.

Comment: Thanks ,It's work now.And could you tell me some other ways to pick out urls from HTML?

Comment: @hession, perhaps you could ask that as a separate question, and be sure to tell us your language/application environment, and give an example of input.